# Someone is using this technology against me and my family. Who can I contact for help

Tags: help, please

Someone is using this technology against me and my family.  Who can I contact for help.

Comment: I'm sorry you are having a problem but this site is about the patent system. Your question is not within the scope of the site and will be closed or possibly deleted.

Comment: What technology? If you are getting here from a link on Google Patents, you’ll have to link us back to the original webpage.